# Chat Application using TCP via 3G

Tags: java, networking, tcp, portforwarding, upnp

Hello everyone I am developing a simple chat application which I want to run it over 3G or mobile data. 
It works fine if my server is behind a router with the listening port forwarded to it. 
But it is not working when I run my server in 3G. 
By surfing many sites I have found out that all the ports are blocked by the ISP. 
Is there any alternate solution for this 3G issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you run a server in 3G? What does that mean?

Comment: I mean i am trying to run the application on a pc which uses a 3g internet connection

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Most cellular connections use carrier-grade NAT, on which you do not have the luxury of opening ports. If you look, you probably have a 10.x.x.x or other private-range IP address, which is not publically routable.

Comment: is there any other solution to establish a connection via 3g?

Comment: You might look into some sort of NAT broker. In general though, you might look into some sort of cloud instance.

Comment: how applications like whatsapp and viber works? Is it possible to implement their connection procedure in my application? I found out that whatsapp works on port 443 or 80.

Comment: You need to understand how the internet works. To what IP address will clients connect?

Comment: In my application my client connects to the server's public ip which is in the range 1.x.x.x.